# USE MY 12V DC AMPLIFIER AT HOME

Tags: heating

How can I use my 12-DC amplifier at my house ? Can I plugged it directly to my socket that has a current of 220 Volts ? Should it be safe ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You have an amplifier that's powered by 12 volts DC, and you want to plug it into 220 volts AC? Don't. Don't, don't, don't, don't, don't, don't, don't, don't, don't, don't, don't.

Comment: Doubtful that this is on-topic since we don't deal with small appliances, but we'd need make and model at the very least. And why did you use the [tag:heating] tag?

Answer (score 3):

> **My 12V DC Amplifier**

There are a huge number of completely different devices that can be described as an "amplifier". Only a subset of them operate using a 12V DC supply. Here is an example:

[image]

However, it doesn't really matter, the advice below applies for any device which requires an **input voltage of 12V DC**

> **How can I use my 12-DC amplifier at my house?**

Find out the power rating of your amplifier. There will be a label that says how many **Watts** it uses. Buy a 12V DC power supply of greater wattage that is designed to plug in to a 220 V AC electricity socket.

If you can't see any mention of Watts on the device, multiple the input voltage by the input current. For example - the device in the picture above has a label with 12V and 12A on it.  12V x 12A = 144 Watts. Don't multiply *input* voltage by *output* current (or vice versa)

[image]

You will need to make sure that the plugs at each end are compatible with your 220V AC socket and with the connector on your amplifier.

> **Can I plugged it directly to my socket that has a current of 220 Volts?**

No, the plug for a 12V DC device should not even fit that socket.

> **Should it be safe?**

No, plugging a 12V DC device directly into a 220V AC socket will very likely destroy the device and cause it to catch fire.

---

If in doubt, I suggest you just take your amplifier to a local electrical store and ask them if they have a "power supply" or "mains adapter" that will suit your amplifier.

Comment: Note that old PC power supplies often had a 12V output, and might be able to supply enough current for this. Or might not.

Answer (score -1):

If your amp has a 220v input it would work other than that you will let the magic smoke out. If it is a 12 V model you will need a transformer to bring the 220 down and a rectifier to turn it back in to DC

Comment: Plus capacitors and probably a voltage regulator. Better to say he needs a 220V to 12V DC power supply which can supply enough current. BTW, to the OP, 220 volts is not current. Current is measured in amps.

Comment: BTW, I didn't give you the down-vote.